# Programs recommended for data recovery

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

My external hard disk is busy packing up. I tried to access the drive to save some photo's, but no success through Windows disk management. So I tried my linux box at work, read up about the fsck cmd on an external drive

---

> *sudo fsck /dev/sdc* and got this
>   "Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
>   fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc"
>   e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
>   ^Ce2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
>   filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
>   filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
>   is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
>   e2fsck -b 8193

---

So next step:

---

> e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdc
>   e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
>   ^Ce2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc

---

As seen from the output above, it looks like it's a bit too late. So I thought one last resort might be to ask for recommendations? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Product recommendations are generally considered off-topic here. http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

What is the disk formatted as ? If you used it as an external drive in windows, it's most likely in FAT.

Can you see the drive at all from Windows ?

Linux has a lot of applications to try to copy the files, like `ddrescue`, that, just like `dd` will copy a drive to another, but it can skip bad sectors, to try them again later. You'll need another drive to hold the image, as big as, or bigger, than your current drive.

Also, if the drive is smaller than 500Gb, you can try [Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) (not free). It helped me repair some drives in the past.

Comment: I have ran Spinrite on 2TB+ drives.  It simply takes awhile if there is a problem.

Comment: Weird, I've tried it on a 1Tb on multiple machines, and it always crashes at the 500Gb mark. Steve Gibson insists that it is just a bios bug, I don't know if I believe him.

Comment: How dare you question the `Bite God` that is Steve Gibson!  All I know is I ran Spinrite 6 on my 1.5TB HDD without a problem.

Comment: Weird, I should make a new question about that. I'm a steve Gibson follower too :) But something seems fishy here.